# MySQL, safely using reserved word in query

Tags: php, mysql, reserved-words

I need to return a multidimensional array from a query with the id keys named `key`. (needed for *object keys* in amazon S3 API)

example:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => 8 ) [1] => Array ( [key] => 7 ) [2] => Array ( [key] => 6 ) )
```

The problem: `key` is a reserved name in MySQL. I **have** to use the name key.

The following query gives an error

```
SELECT `file_name` AS key FROM (`uploads`)
```

but adding backticks around `key` doesn't give errors

```
SELECT `file_name` AS `key` FROM (`uploads`)
```

Is it safe to continue like this or is there a better way? I was thinking to rename the id key in the array in PHP but doing it in the query seems faster

Comment: yes thats what the backticks are for

Comment: I'll recommend not to use reserved words, but if you **must** use them, then **always** use backticks.

Comment: It's safe - it wouldn't work otherwise. But it's a good idea not to use reserved words if you can, because it makes the code that bit harder to follow.

Comment: I recount instances wherein a SQL Function returned results with pure  numeric column-names. The situation aggravates with the wrappers of various scripting environment such as PHP. Consider using aliases through `AS aliasname` in those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, use backticks.

From the [MYSQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE interval (begin INT, end INT);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax ...
near 'interval (begin INT, end INT)'

mysql> CREATE TABLE `interval` (begin INT, end INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

To be away from reserved keyword around table field in query always considered as the best way...If you are using in reserved keyword in query, then `backtick` allow you to use reserved keyword...

As `backtick` is not defined in `ANSI SQL` standard, it'll probably create problem when you migrate from MySQL environment...