# error when writing variable to mysql via python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert with python (v 2.7.6) a variable with multiple entries into MySQL (Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43) table. The code is as follows :

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Stations(     \
            StationsID  INT AUTO_INCREMENT,           \
            Code      VARCHAR(3)       ,              \
            PRIMARY KEY pk_Stations (StationsID)      \
            );");

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Stations (Code) VALUES(?)", sns);
```

`sns` variable has the following form:

`array(['PAL', 'TT1', 'BAL', 'MHD', 'BI5', 'CB4'],dtype='|S3')`

I am getting the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 199, in executemany
    if not args: return
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Could you please give me a help here?

Comment: DUpe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546267/mysql-safely-using-reserved-word-in-query

Comment: I tried with the `` notation but same error..

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The variable should be a list and it was a `numpy` array.